# Broken link in the 'Do Trilogy Sites Need a "Third Place"?' blog post

Tags: bug, broken-link, blog

Namely, http://blog.stackexchange.com/post/518474918/stack-exchange-2-0, and the post is https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/04/do-trilogy-sites-need-a-third-place/.

I'm not sure if this will achieve anything, but the 404 page advises to report broken links. So, here it is!

Comment: It's not just that it is a broken link, it is [gone](https://encrypted.google.com/search?q=stack+exchange+2.0) and [gone](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=stack+exchange+2.0+blog) so all the links to it are broken.

Comment: https://web.archive.org/web/20111007091110/http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/04/changes-to-stack-exchange/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://github.com/StackExchange/stack-blog/pull/257 , thanks, [@Braiam](/q/335189/648265#comment399750_335216) and [@DavidG](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/335216/648265)!

Comment: @AdamLear to tell you the truth, _content_ of a 3rd party site being _in freakin' public version control_ is something unimaginable! Way to go!

Answer (score 12):

The link is indeed broken, but The Internet Archive helps us figure out where to go. The last time it was crawled as a working link was on 25th April 2010. Some time between then and 21st June 2010 the link died due to the blog being moved around. We can see from [this link](http://web.archive.org/web/20100621062826/http://blog.stackexchange.com/post/518474918/stack-exchange-2-0) that a redirect was put into place to:

https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/04/changes-to-stack-exchange/

Which is where you will find the blog now!

Comment: That's an interesting link. So they used to charge for SE. I wonder what's the biggest SE site that was paid for by users? and were there any that were popular but went under when the founder couldn't afford it?

Comment: I think http://mathoverflow.net/ was one of the paid for sites, and is still active

Comment: You can submit a pull request to fix the links.

Comment: @Braiam A PR to where exactly?

Comment: https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2015/07/how-we-built-our-blog/